# Entity Framework - ExecuteFunction<T> returns null instead of exception

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a very simple stored procedure which I am using to test something:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [cms].[TestSPROC]
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @Test INT 

    SELECT *,CONVERT(NUMERIC(3,2),15) AS Test
    FROM Viper.Currencies

END
```

The SP should return an arithmetic overflow exception, and does so within SQL Server Management studio.

**The problem:** 
When calling the SP in my application using the Entity Framework's `.ExecuteFunction<T>` method, **null is returned instead of an EntityException being thrown**. (The same thing happens when using the function import, but that essentially just calls `.ExecuteFunction<T>` anyway)

Here is my code:

```
using (CmsEntities context = new CmsEntities())
{
    try
    {
        context.ExecuteFunction<TestSPROCResult>("TestSPROC");
    }
    catch (EntityException exc)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
    }
}
```

If I call `context.ExecuteFunction("TestSPROC");` the exception is thrown and handled, so maybe the problem has something to do with the complex type.

Has anyone ever encountered/managed to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ExecuteFunction returns an entity set, but the execution is delayed until it actually is needed. So in your example, the function is never actually called.

Try

```
context.ExecuteFunction<TestSPROCResult>("TestSPROC").ToList();
```

to force the execution

Comment: This solved the problem in the case of my question, but not the underlying problem of EF ignoring an arithmetic overflow exception in some cases. Accepted though, since it worked for this case, thanks :)